# ¿Como hacer un historial de procesos para la producción de un calzado?

Tags: php, mysql

no se como podría crear un historial en mi base de datos, por ejemplo: tengo un formulario donde registro ordenes de producción de un calzado, a esas ordenes les asigno un proceso. Ejemplo: Corte, Aparado, Armado y Acabado; y esta orden va ir cambiando de procesos, entonces quiero guardar el historial de esos cambios y posteriormente identificar en que proceso se encuentra una orden y por que procesos ha pasado además de jalar y guardar los demás id de las otras tablas, para saber sus respectivos datos.

Estas son mis tablas:

### ORDENES

ORD_id PK
USU_id FK
CLI_id FK
ORD_estado

### ORDENES_DETALLES

ODET_id FK
ODET_material
ODET_suela
ODET_color
ODET_observacion
ODET_fechaOrden
ODET_fechaentrega
PRO_id FK -> hace referencia los productos.
SER_id FK -> hace referencia a las tallas o series.

### PROC_id FK - hace referencia a los procesos.

### PROCESOS

PROC_id PK
PROC_nombre
PROC_descripcion
PROC_precio
PROC_total
PROC_fecha
PROC_estado

### EMP_id FK -> hace referencia a los empreados.

### SERIES

SER_id PK
SER_tallas

### EMPLEADOS

EMP_id PK
EMP_nombres
EMP_apellidos

### ...

Comment: con los nombres es complicado entender, pero si lo que quieres es tener un historico de los procesos de una misma orden lo mejor es crear una tabla procesos_orden, con el id del proceso y el id de la orden, con sus timestamps y asi podras consultarlas en orden cronologico